# Are there GHC optimizations working during library builds?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

Are there any such optimizaitons in GHC which work only during library build and can not be used during building resulting executable. So the question is whether there could be a difference in resulting binary coming from the fact that the libraries on which it depends were compiled with no optimization flags enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC supports separate compilation. So yes, libraries may well have been compiled with different flags to the application that uses the library.

Comment: Thanks but would you mind to elaborate with regard to optimizations? Which of them will suffer from separate compilation?

Comment: GHC unrolls definitions into .hi files, so that cross-packaging optimizations will still fire under -O levels.